# pass list of dictionaries as command line arguments

Tags: python

I would like to pass list of dictionaries as command line argument as follows

```
python test.py [{'name': 'student1', 'grade': 'A'}, {'name': 'student2', 'grade': 'A'}, {'name': 'student3', 'grade': 'C'}]
```

and would like access this this list ?

Comment: Maybe you could pass a json string instead.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to achieve this is probably treating this as a json:

`python test.py "[{'name': 'student1', 'grade': 'A'}, {'name': 'student2', 'grade': 'A'}, {'name': 'student3', 'grade': 'C'}]"`
Note the extra `"`.

The code then:

```
import json
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
   print("Usage: python test.py \"<dictionary-list>\"")
   sys.exit(-1)

try:
   command_line_dict_list = json.loads(sys.argv[1].replace("'", '"'))
except json.JSONDecodeError:
   print("Usage: python test.py \"<dictionary-list>\"")
   print("Note: the dictionary should only contain strings and numbers")
   sys.exit(-1)

print(command_line_dict_list) 
# [{'name': 'student1', 'grade': 'A'}, {'name': 'student2', 'grade': 'A'}, {'name': 'student3', 'grade': 'C'}]
print(type(command_line_dict_list))
# <class 'list'>
```

Note `sys.argv[0]` will contain your program name - aka `"test.py"`

This should do the trick.